# Greedy algorithm for knapsack in java

Tags: java, knapsack-problem

I am trying to write a very simple greedy algorithm for the knapsack problem. My inputs are two parallel arrays. One array contains the value of the item and the other array contains the weights.

The greedy algorithm that I’m trying to write would go as follows: check which item has the highest value and put this in the knapsack. Then set the value of this item to zero. Check again which item has the highest value and put it in the knapsack if the knapsack can still hold it. If it can hold it, set the value again to zero (after you’ve put it in) and start looking for the highest value again. If that knapsack cannot hold it anymore then just end the program.

I know that there are a lot of better greedy algorithms out there but this seems to me to be a pretty simple one and I think I could manage this. My problem is that I have to go through the entire values array to find the maximum value. Then when I’ve found it I put it in the knapsack and set the value to zero. But the problem then is that I have to go back in the for loop to find the new highest value item and put this in the knapsack. But I don’t know how I would go about doing this.

I am writing this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you usually solve Knapsack greedily by using the highest ratio value/weight instead of just the value.

Secondly, you do not need to search for the maximum in each step if you sort the list of items once and go through it step by step.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I know that there are a number of ways to solve the Knapsack using a greedy algorithm and I have already seen and used one with the highest ratio of value/weight. I just wanted to try all different kinds to practice in programming as I am an absolute beginner.

The problem with sorting them first and then just iterating through them is that my weight index then no longer corresponds to my value index so that I can no longer check if it still fits inside the knapsack. I thought that the way I was going to do it might be a workaround around this problem.

Comment: There's a correspondence between the weights and values (i.e. they can't be arbitrarily rearranged). At the moment it sounds like you're storing the weights and values in separate arrays and trying to enforce that correspondence purely by the order of the arrays. You could encapsulate that information by making a simple class which holds value/weight of an item, you can then create and sort an array of those objects without having to keep track manually of which weight and value belong together.